# wp_insert_post / wp_update_post Duplications

Tags: wordpress

I'm importing from a JSON file and I get duplicates every time the importer runs.

The foreach

```
        $name = $data->name;
        $desc = $data->description;
        $type = $data->type;
        $tutor = $data->tutor;
        $location = $data->location;
        $planned_start = $data->planned_start;
        $actual_start = $data->actual_start;
        $actual_end = $data->actual_end;
        $max_attendees = $data->max_attendees;
```

The importer

```
$check_title = get_page_by_title( $name);
            $my_post = array(
                'ID' => $check_title->ID,
                'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($name),
                'post_type' => 'training',
                'post_content' => $desc,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'meta_input' => array(
                    'course_type' => $type,
                    'tutor' => $tutor,
                    'location' => $location,
                    'planned_start' => $planned_start,
                    'actual_start' => $actual_start,
                    'actual_end' => $actual_end,
                    'max_attendees' => $max_attendees,
                ),
                'tax_input' => array(
                    'custom_cat_training' => $type,
                ),

            );  
        if (empty($check_title)){ 
           $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $type, 'custom_cat_training');
         
        } else {
           $post_id = wp_update_post($my_post);
           wp_set_object_terms($check_title->ID, $type, 'custom_cat_training');
        }
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't for the life of me work it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it with it

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/

```
 if (!post_exists($name)){ 
           $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $type, 'custom_cat_training');
         
        } else {
           $post_id = wp_update_post($my_post);
           wp_set_object_terms($check_title->ID, $type, 'custom_cat_training');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that just breaks the importer. Nothing is added or updated.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: could you please check this example, how to use?

Answer (score 0):

I used  get_page_by_path($trimmed, OBJECT, 'training');

and used the page slug rather than title